# Updating MySql counter when users log in

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, updating

I have a website where users can log in.  The client wants there to be a way to record the number of times any particular user logs in.  I have a "Counter" row in the table.  How do I program the app (built in C# ASP.NET) to update the counter when people log in?  Is this code correct:

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery = "UPDATE Counter FROM brokercenter"

I just recently graduated (as in the 10th of this month) so I am new to this, plus I know nothing about databases, I am just learning on the job.  Please let me know if I need any other parameter or connection string or aything else?  This is in the button click event and there is already a connection string there to check the username and password so I don't think I need another connection string, but I don;t know for sure.  Thanks in advance!

For that matter, here is the whole event (the login stuff works fine, just the update is my question):

```
string connectionString =         
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["moverschoiceConnectionString"].ConnectionString;    
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);   
conn.Open();   OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();   
cmd.Connection = conn;   
cmd.CommandText = "select Email, Password from brokercenter where Email = '" + txtLoginEmail.Text + "'";   
OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();   

while(reader.Read())   
{     
    if (reader["Password"].ToString() == txtLoginPassword.Text)     
    {         
        reader.Close();
        if (cbRememberMe.Checked == true)
        {
            Response.Cookies["username"].Value = txtLoginEmail.Text;
            Response.Cookies["username"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
            Response.Cookies["password"].Value = txtLoginPassword.Text;
            Response.Cookies["password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Cookies["username"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
            Response.Cookies["password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
        }

            Response.Redirect("BrokerResources.aspx");     
        }     
        else     
        {         
            lblLoginError.Text = "Invalid Password";     
        }   
    }   
    lblLoginError.Text = "Invalid Email or Password";    
    reader.Close();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery = "UPDATE counter FROM brokercenter";
}
```

Comment: You might want to read up on basic SQL syntax first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Queries  while we can help fix broken code (if you provide it), we're not here to be your teachers for basics.

Comment: Sorry for thinking this is a community to help people.  I am not asking you to sit next to me and teach me databases (though I would not mind it, haha), I am asking for help though.  I do not know how to do this and directing me to wikipedia further confuses me.  Consider my code broken in that it does not work, hehe.

Comment: read up on the syntax of update queries, and you'll see why the counter isn't updating (hint: because you're not writing a proper query).

Answer (score 3):

For a start, you should read about using `UPDATE` in [MySQL's Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).

There is even an example for exactly what you want to do.
Quote from the link:

> If you access a column from the table to be updated in an expression,
>   UPDATE uses the current value of the column. For example, the
>   following statement sets col1 to one more than its current value:
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1;
> ```

This is basically all you need, you just need to add a `WHERE` clause and filter for the username or for the email.

Plus, you should read about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) because of this:

```
where Email = '" + txtLoginEmail.Text + "'";
```

Concatenating strings like this to pass parameters can cause problems as described in the link.
[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2775692/6884) how to do it better.

Comment: So do I not need the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery part in there?  I thought that is what increments it.

Comment: Yes, you **do** need `ExecuteNonQuery`. I mentioned only the SQL in my answer because my impression was that your main problem is how to get the `UPDATE` query right (the one you posted in the question is not valid SQL). But you still need `ExecuteNonQuery` to actually **execute** the query.

Comment: Ok, just checking, that is in there like I thought. Thank you guys for all your help! I am one piece of the puzzle away from being done with this project.

Answer (score -1):

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery = String.Format("UPDATE brokercenter SET counter = {0} WHERE Email = {1}", myCounter++, txtLoginEmail.Text);
```

where "myCounter" is a local counter variable (which should also be read from the database). Does this make sense now?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I was reading up on the update queries like the other poster had suggested, and for the most part I had it right as I was redoing it, but that ExecuteNonQuery was confusing me.  Thank you!

Comment: -1 because it's: a) vulnerable to SQL injection (see my answer about that); b) won't work as written because `Email` is a string; c) increasing a counter variable in C# is not the best way to update a value in a SQL table.

Comment: Excellent feedback, Christian!! What I really was trying was to make a quick point and get @hammer.pr going...